# my hr style doesnt appear in mobile browsers

Tags: css, styles

My HR is as below:

```
    <hr style='height: 20px; background: url(stars.png) no-repeat center;     border: none;' />
```

It works fine on pc browser chrome, mozilla etc. It shows me a line of stars but when i open my website from android mobile, HR is not there at all.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the problem ? please see my code

```html
<hr style='height: 20px; background: url(http://pngimg.com/upload/star_PNG1597.png) repeat center; border: none;background-size: 20px 20px;' />
```